# Question regarding medical technicians and driving on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

If an ambulance arrived at a hospital on Shabbos with a Jewish 2 man crew, and the second (non driving) medical technician does not have a driver's license, and there is another (non-medical) person there, who has a car & wants to return to his home from the hospital-

If the ambulance may be needed for other emergencies, and therefore its driver may drive the ambulance back to its place of origin, may he leave the second (non driving) medical technician, who may also be needed for future emergencies, at the hospital, in order to allow the 3rd non-medical person to drive him back with his own car?

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost in some of this. If the non-driving technician is needed for future emergencies, why isn't he riding back in the ambulance? In other words, there seems to be a "definition" here that the person's "work" as a technician which allows him to violate Shabbat is that he is either in an ambulance or in a hospital, etc. involved with the emergency. A private car is not meant for emergencies. It sounds like you are "planning" the use of a private car in case the 2nd technician has an emergency. I don't think you can plan things this way, when you had the other option.

Comment: @DanF Correction- The 2nd technician must return to his hometown in order to be available for future emergencies. He does not have the option of remaining at the hospital. My question is whether knowing that the 3rd person wants to go home too, may the ambulance driver leave the hospital without taking his partner along with him in the ambulance, in order to enable the 3rd person to drive him home with his private car, and thus get himself back home too?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I'm inclined to say "No". The ambulance driver definitely had permission to drive back, and he can take a rider. (If I'm correct, there is no melacha for someone to ride in a car - even if, say, it was the car owner.) The non-driving medic does need to return, too. But by leaving him in the hospital, you, in a sense, "force" him to drive back the other medic in his own car, when, in actuality, the other medic had another viable non-melcaha option available.

Comment: @DanF "*by leaving him in the hospital, you, in a sense, "force" him to drive back the other medic in his own car, when, in actuality, the other medic had another viable non-melcaha option available.*" What would be the problem with causing someone to have to do something on shabbat which is pikuach nefesh, if  before that he had another option but at the time of his action he no longer does?Do you have  a source that this is forbidden?

Comment: @DanF המבשל או עשה שאר מלאכה לחולה, אסור בשבת לבריא או לחולה שאין בו סכנה, דחישינן שמא ירבה בשבילו - אורח חיים שיח ב  - A rider may not ride along in the Ambulance, since he might drive extra for his sake.

Comment: @DanF your 2nd comment rasies a point just as interesting as the question itself- no melacha riding in a car on Shabbat? Just driving? I've never heard that (except from movements within Judaism that hold nothing at all to be melacha, of course). Do you happen to have a source handy on that? Could I potentially arrange to have a gentile pick me up at shul on Friday evening on the promise he'll be paid on Saturday night?

Comment: @JoshK having a gentile pick you up at shul on Friday evening would be forbidden because of אמירה לנכרי - A jew is forbidden to tell a goy to do something on Shabbos which he is forbidden to do.

Comment: True, @RibbisRabbiAndMore...what if I knew the goy and he happened to drive by shul just as services were ending and said, "hop in"?

Comment: @JoshK Not only telling a goy to do a melacha is a problem. Allowing a goy to do a melacha for you is also forbidden. And entering the car may be even worse since hes not doing it on his own but you are getting inside which might be like telling him to do it.

Comment: @JoshK Ribbis correctly mentioned the main problem. But there have been some opinions stating that one may ride the New York City subway on Shabbat providing that one doesn't need to pay the fare or carry anything. Here, the subway is working and stopping at its stops not specifically for you. The fare & carrying are separate problems unrelated to riding. As long as the transportation is not specifically for you, there's no problem riding it.

Comment: @DanF And soooo??? We're discussing here whether one may ride in a car on shabbos, not whether he can take the subway.

Comment: @ribbis I'm using the subway as an example. See my last sentence. I said that as long as the transport is operated by a Gentile and its running not specifically for you, a Jew may use it.

Comment: See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3760

Comment: I didn't see a problem with the question, even if it does present a "complex scenario". (I've read the meta explanation, numerous times, and I still can't really figure it out.) I'm curious if the recent downvotes came as a result of the comments following my answer; namely an "additional" criteria / question that wasn't originally mentioned. If so, I think that creates an "unfair bias".

Comment: Dan A when I "added in the comments asking whos respnsibilty it was, that was to explain what I meant by "Is it allowed?" If the onus cant be put on anyone there cannot be such an obligation! (for the 2nd med. not to go back), so its not a new point its part and parcel of the original.

Answer (score 2):

See O.C. 328:10 that says that while one may violate Shabat rules for *choleh sheyesh sakanah*, one should try to do as little *melacha* as possible. Thus, if a Gentile could drive the ambulance, they should do that.

In this case, even though there is no immediate *choleh* on returning back to ambulance base, the point is that the medic can drive the ambulance back to base because they must have an ambulance ready for even a *safek* sakanah (i.e., in case another emergency may occur.) So, the other medic, who is also needed, should ride back in the ambulance. If they had a Gentile who could drive the ambulance, they should use him, but, apparently, they don't so the next available "minimal" level is using the ambulance driver.

using the Jew who is in the hospital who wants to get back home, would be on a "higher" level of *melacha* as he is not a doctor and is not reacting to an emergency - at least not on the same level as the ambulance driver. I.e. be using the other Jew, you are "increasing" the melacha "usage".

Comment: I ask again- Whith whom would the problem be?  The ambulance driver may drive back. What would "Obligate" him  to take the other medic along with him? . Once he leaves the other medic "stranded" he has no choice but to be driven back by the non-medical person. So who is doing something wrong?

Comment: @ribbis i don't see that in your question. You asked if one is allowed to leave the second guy so that he can go with a different driver back home, and that is answered very well in this post. If you wanna change the question, you must do so before answers are posted, or post a new question with that info.

Comment: @aBochur I did not change my question. So if you understood my question as "if one (the ambulance driver) is allowed to leave the second guy so that he can go with a different driver back home" , Can you please show me where his answer tells me why he cannot?

Comment: @ribbis "one should try to do as little melachaas possible." 3rd line of the answer

Comment: @aBochur So who is this "ONE" he/ you are referring to in regard to this question? The ambulance driver? what fewer melachos is he doing if he does or doesnt take the other medic along with him?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore my understanding is that everyone involved must make sure that the least amount of melacha would be performed. Therefore, they are not allowed to stage this situation in order to drive a car on shabbos. Period. Who gets punished if this does happen? Now that's a different question

Comment: I think that this is the 2nd question of yours that I have recently answered that has a "follow up". There's nothing wrong with that. However, what you're asking in the comments is just that - a follow up. It was NOT an aspect that you relayed in your original question. You did NOT ask "who has the problem?" All you asked was "is the car driver allowed to drive?" My answer explains why not. You can agree or disagree with the answer. But you can't really state that it isn't answering your question based on your introducing an unmentioned aspect that no one knows about, beforehand.

Comment: " Once he leaves the other medic "stranded" he has no choice but to be driven back by the non-medical person. So who is doing something wrong?" Apparently, the driver is doing something wrong if he drives. I explained why in my answer. In summary, you are supposed to minimize the chance of doing melacha. The way to do that is by having the 2nd medic ride back with the ambulance driver. Additionally, since the driver is not a medic, he is not directly the one responding to a *pikuach nefesh*. So the onus is not on him to do anything. (continued)...

Comment: The non-driving medic would be the one responsible to find a solution. Here, too, he needs to minimize melacha meaning that he should ideally find a Gentile driver. But, again, he would have minimized this better had he just ridden back with the ambulance driver.